# 12.04 upgrade lost gb keyboard layout

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, layout

Upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04. Keyboard Layout from System Settings only shows us listed in options but `/etc/default/keyboard` contains:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

`/etc/X11/xkb` is empty, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` does not exist.

How do I recover UK keyboard layout so I can find # " @ etc in the right place again?

Thanks

Comment: /etc/X11/xkb hasn't been used in a while. What's in /usr/share/X11/xkb ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on a Virtualbox guest lubuntu 12.10. I'm using an OSX host, the keyboard is mac. I've been able to get lubuntu to recognise the keyboard by editing:

```
/etc/default/keyboard
```

to

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb(mac)"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Hope this helps anyone similarly stuck.